# Unit Test With Code coverage using jasmine

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, code-coverage, spy

I have simple logger .ts file .I am try to do unit test on that .If some one help me to fix my unit test.

logging.service.ts

```
import 'reflect-metadata'; // Required for tsyringe
import { singleton } from 'tsyringe';
import { Category } from 'typescript-logging';
@singleton()
export class Logger {
private logger: Category;
constructor(){
this.logger = new Category('oidc-security-logger');
}
trace(msg: string): void {
this.logger.trace(msg);
}
debug(msg: string): void {
this.logger.debug(msg);
}
info(msg: string): void {
this.logger.info(msg);
}
warn(msg: string): void {
this.logger.warn(msg);
}
error(msg: string, error?: Error): void {
if(error){
 this.logger.error(msg, error);
 } else {
 this.logger.error(msg, null);
 }
 }
 fatal(msg: string, error?: Error): void {
 if (error) {
   this.logger.fatal(msg, error);
 } else {
      this.logger.fatal(msg, null);
   }
  }
 }
```

I have tried with following method to complete my unit test.
logging.service.spec.ts

```
import { Logger } from "./logging.service";    

describe("Logger", () => {    
let loggerMok: Logger;    
beforeEach(() => {
 loggerMok = new Logger();
});

it("should be test logger", () => {
const msg='This is for test';
spyOn(loggerMok,'trace').and.stub();
spyOn(loggerMok,'debug').and.stub();
spyOn(loggerMok,'info').and.stub();
spyOn(loggerMok,'warn').and.stub();
spyOn(loggerMok,'error').and.stub();
spyOn(loggerMok,'fatal').and.stub();
loggerMok.trace(msg);
loggerMok.debug(msg);
loggerMok.info(msg);
loggerMok.warn(msg);
loggerMok.error(msg);
loggerMok.fatal(msg);
expect(loggerMok.trace).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(loggerMok.debug).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(loggerMok.info).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(loggerMok.warn).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(loggerMok.error).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(loggerMok.fatal).toHaveBeenCalled();

});
});
```

This unit test is working fine but code coverage is not giving score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `callThrough` instead of `stub`. When you `stub` it won't call the actual implementation and basically just ignore the call. Check out [Method stubs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_stub) for more info.

When you use `callThrough` it would call the actual implementation thus adding coverage. So you can use something like:

```
it("should be test logger", () => {
const msg='This is for test';
spyOn(loggerMok,'trace').and.callThrough();
spyOn(loggerMok,'debug').and.callThrough();
spyOn(loggerMok,'info').and.callThrough();
spyOn(loggerMok,'warn').and.callThrough();
spyOn(loggerMok,'error').and.callThrough();
spyOn(loggerMok,'fatal').and.callThrough();
loggerMok.trace(msg);
loggerMok.debug(msg);
loggerMok.info(msg);
loggerMok.warn(msg);
loggerMok.error(msg);
loggerMok.fatal(msg);
expect(loggerMok.trace).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(loggerMok.debug).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(loggerMok.info).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(loggerMok.warn).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(loggerMok.error).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(loggerMok.fatal).toHaveBeenCalled();

});
});
```

But this test case is not very useful since all you do is call it and then check if it's called. Instead I would recommend spying on the `new Category` and check if that has been called.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response .I have done with your suggestion.                                                                      
Giving good mutation score 87.50% but code coverage  54.17%.

Comment: You can also invoke loggerMok.error(msg, error);
loggerMok.fatal(msg, error) to increase coverage

Comment: Yes I have done with that and current score is 100%

Comment: spyOn(loggerMok, 'fatal').and.callThrough();
  loggerMok.fatal(msg, error);
  expect(loggerMok.fatal).toHaveBeenCalled();
  loggerMok.fatal(msg);
  expect(loggerMok.fatal).toHaveBeenCalled();